# Make 2nd API call in the background after 1st one ends in an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-observables

```
public LoggedInUser$:Observable<any> = new Observable(observer => {
        this._loggedInUser = observer;
        this.api$.make_api_call('getapplication').subscribe(d => {
           // do Something            
        });
    });
```

How do I latch on another API call to this observable that'd be asynchronous or at least fired up after the response of `getapplication`? I tried adding in another API call inside like -

```
        let params = {
            'all_applications': true
        };
        this.api$.make_api_call('getallapplications', params).subscribe(d => {
            // do Something           
        });
```

but it doesn't solve my purpose and both the calls are made almost simultaneously.

These are two separate calls and not dependent on each other. Idea is to bring in individual application data for the user and once that's done, running an async call (or maybe something in the background) to get rest of the applications and cache it in Redis.

The requirement is to bring in a single application data for a customer. At the same time bringing in all the other applications data so that when user switches between it, user experience doesn't suffer.

Comment: Are these 2 APIs dependent or independent?

Comment: @ngShravil.py independent. But I want 2nd one to be fired after 1st one and run in the background to fetch the rest of the data in Redis.

Comment: Then, you can make use of `forkJoin`. This will call multiple API's in parallel manner.

Comment: By the way, what is the requirement that you are choosing this type of approach?

Comment: @ngShravil.py The requirement is to bring in a single application data for a customer. At the same time bringing in all the other applications data so that when user switches between it, user experience doesn't suffer.

Comment: What if an applications data is loaded for a user, other applications data are still loading and the user switches at this moment?

Comment: There's already contingency for that to pull individual application data with application data-id.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try **concatMap**? ConcatMap helps you to process the requests in sequence i.e ones you get the response for first your next call gets executed.

```js
import { of  } from 'rxjs'; 
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
import { map, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


 const users$ = ajax.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users');

users$.pipe(
      concatMap(users => {
        const userId = 1;
        console.log('concat users', users)
        return ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${userId}`)
    })
 ).subscribe(user => console.log('user', user));
```

Here is the stackblitz URL

[concatMap RXJS example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lkzp3f)

In your case, try this

```js
this.api$.make_api_call('getapplication').pipe(
  tap(response => console.log('First API response'),
  concatMap(response => {
    let params = {
              'all_applications': true
    };
     return this.api$.make_api_call('getallapplications', params)
  })
).subscribe(response => console.log('2nd API Response', response));
```

Comment: Thanks, @prathameshk73. However, these two are independent calls and 2nd one is not bothered about the values from the first one. Think of it as making a first SO API call to get your user profile and simultaneously running a background call to get all Angular questions for you to access later on.

Comment: Nope. Only when 1st one executes.